# SQL Server: count transaction

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this table in SQL Server:

[image: table]

I want a result like this

[image]

I am going to write SQL queries to count the transaction and consolidate every month.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is your `TXN Date` column `varchar` or `date` type?

Comment: TXN Date column is a int type

Comment: Divide it by 100 and use `group by` like this `SELECT TXNDate / 100, COUNT(*) FROM Table1 GROUP BY TXNDate / 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to edit the column you want to group.

```
SELECT
    A.YYYYMM,
    COUNT(*) TxnCount
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        LEFT(TXN_DATE, 6) YYYYMM
    FROM
        Tbl
) A
GROUP BY
    A.YYYYMM
```

Comment: wonderful, learnt something new today. always thought `LEFT` was `char` type specific :)

Comment: turns out [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms177601.aspx) converts the `int` to a `char`

Comment: `LEFT(Input, 2)` Type of result will be type of input.

Comment: documentation says: _Returns varchar when character_expression is a non-Unicode character data type.
Returns nvarchar when character_expression is a Unicode character data type._

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` clause to count the transaction.
Assuming your `TXN Date` is of `date` type, you can use following query:

```
SELECT    CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TXN_DATE, 112) AS YYYYMM, COUNT(*) AS TXN_COUNT
FROM      MyTable
GROUP BY  CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TXN_DATE, 112)
ORDER BY  CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TXN_DATE, 112)
```

EDIT: since your `TXN_DATE` is `int` type, you can use the following

```
SELECT    LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, TXN_DATE), 6) AS YYYYMM, COUNT(*) AS TXN_COUNT
FROM      MyTable
GROUP BY  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, TXN_DATE), 6)
ORDER BY  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, TXN_DATE), 6)
```

Comment: TXN Date column is a int type

Answer (score 0):

Use **Group By** and **Substring** :

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(CAST(TXNDate AS VARCHAR(12)),0,9) AS TXNDate,COUNT(*) AS 'TXN Count'
FROM
@tblTest
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CAST(TXNDate AS VARCHAR(12)),0,9)
```

Comment: TXN Date column is a int type